# How to embed an arcgis dashboard in my website

Tags: embed, dashboard, arcgis

I want the arcgis dashboard to be on my website, so users don't have to log out

I've searched several places and still haven't found the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use `iframe` tag in your application and pass your arcgis dashboard URL as `src`.

PS: Your dashboard will be visible in your website but it will prompt for login if your dashboard is not public.

```html
<body>
    <iframe src="YOUR DASHBOARD URL"></iframe>
</body>
```